Is `std::function` deprecated by `std::copyable_function` in C++26?
C++26 provides std::copyable_function [cppref link]. However, the existing std::function is already copyable. So, I have 3 questions:

What are the key advantages of std::copyable_function over std::function?

Invoking an empty std::copyable_function is undefined, while invoking an empty std::function will throw an exception. What's the rationale behind?

Is std::function deprecated by std::copyable_function in C++26?



Related https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1799a6n/wtf_is_stdcopyable_function_has_the_committee/?rdt=41825

And paper https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2548r6.pdf

@康桓瑋 Invoking an empty std::copyable_function is undefined, while invoking an empty std::function will throw an exception. What's the rationale behind? The two links you two provide don't state.


It fixes the "infamous constness-bug", handle const/ref qualifier/noexcept.



What are the key advantages of std::copyable_function over std::function?

There are two.
First, there's no target() API, which generally wasn't super useful anyway, so there's less overhead because std::copyable_function doesn't have to track something that std::function did. But that's minor.
The more important one is the API surface. std::function looks like this:
struct function<R(Args...)> {
    R operator()(Args...) const;
};

The call operator (1) always const and (2) never noexcept. (1) is a problem because you can still invoke a non-const member function without you intending to.
std::copyable_function looks like this:
struct copyable_function<R(Args...) cv ref noexc> {
  R operator()(Args...) cv ref noexc;
};

Meaning that, for instance, copyable_function<void(int)> has a non-const, non-noexcept call operator, but copyable_function<void(int) const noexcept> has one that is both const and noexcept. All of this is specifiable.
This makes the usage clear and descriptive... and more correct!

Invoking an empty std::copyable_function is undefined, while invoking an empty std::function will throw an exception. What's the rationale behind?

Arguably, invoking an empty std::function is a bug. There are many people who think that throwing to signal programmer error is a bad way to do so - calling it undefined behavior means the implementation can assert.

Is std::function deprecated by std::copyable_function in C++26?

The literal answer to this question is: no. But maybe the more interesting question is: should it have been? To which I would still answer no.
There's a very large amount of code that uses std::function and a large percentage of it is likely correct. It's also not a simple renaming to transition either, since many uses will want to change from function<R(Args...)> to copyable_function<R(Args...) const>. But also many uses will want to change to move_only_function<R(Args...) const> instead.
It's probably a good idea to actually make those changes (especially if you don't need target(), which ... nobody does). But they're not so pressing that you actually want a [[deprecated]] warning out of it. Seems more like a low-key clang-tidy modernization hint kind of suggestion.
There's really two levels here:

A is bad (possibly actively harmful), B is strictly superior, please switch.
A is fine, B is better. Prefer B in new code, but A isn't harmful.

Transitioning from auto_ptr<T> to unique_ptr<T> fits into that first category. Transitioning from function<R(Args..)> to copyable_function<R(Args...) const> (or move_only_function<R(Args...) const>, or sometimes even function_ref<R(Args...) const>) to me is more like the second category. A is fine. Don't yell at me for still using it in older code.

I mean, target means that std::function can act as an any; so if you want (say) a std::function augmented to support sorting or hashing, target plus some other stuff can be used.  It is very niche, I'll admit, and storing RTTI every time you create a std::function is overkill for the need.

If assert is better, why not just make calling an empty copyable_function call assert? It being undefined behaviour just means I have to now worry about every copyable_function which might be empty causing time UB-permitted travelling arbitary memory corruption nonsense.

@ChrisJefferson What makes you think it won't?

Those aren't standard assertions, you need to specially enabled. In the next gcc release (nothing released so far), they will get turned on at -O0, but not at anything higher, so your optimised released software will still be full of UB.

https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1745

@ChrisJefferson you can still enable those assertions explicitly for optimized builds using -fhardened
